# Git: Put an existing repository on a shared server

Tags: git

I've tried to follow the instructions from the official git documentation to put an existing repository on a shared server. But when I try to clone the repository on the server I get an error. Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

**[On local machine]**

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
vim test.txt
[insert]some text
[escape]:wq
git init
git add *.*
git commit -m 'First commit.'
cd ..
scp -r temp user@12.345.67.890:/home/user
```

**[On server]**

```
git clone --bare --shared temp temp.git
> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/temp.git/
rm -rf temp // if I don't delete temp I don't get an error, but it doesn't make sense to leave it there
```

**[On local machine]**

```
git clone ssh://user@12.345.67.890:/home/user/temp.git temp2
> Cloning into 'temp2'...
user@12.345.67.890's password:
> error: object directory /home/user/temp/.git/objects does not exist; check .git/ojects/info/alternates.
> fatal: git upload-pack: cannot find object b85fsdg87sg9sg877sg79s7g79sg7:
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I suspect is the .git in the repo name, try on server to call the repo temp_origin, avoiding the .git that seems to cause troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative method that works. I could not make the method from the official documentation work - I tried for about half a day.

**[On server]**

```
$ git init --bare --shared temp.git
```

**[On local]**

```
$ cd temp
$ git remote add origin ssh://user@12.345.67.890:/home/user/temp.git
$ git push origin master

$ git clone ssh://user@12.345.67.890:/home/user/temp.git temp2
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to do in your question with `scp` and which documentation you were following; afaik this is the recommended way to do this stuff, so +1 on figuring out yourself.